How to match brackets in imapfilter Subject search?
I use imapfilter that uses a Lua script as config.
I am trying to match emails subjects containing [sometext] at any position.
So I tried:
results = account1.INBOX:contain_subject('[sometext]')

This performs a search on the server side.
It generates the following IMAP command:
UID SEARCH CHARSET "ISO-8859-15" ALL SUBJECT "[sometext]"

But it matches sometext even without the brackets.
Same thing happens for:
    results = account1.INBOX:match_subject('%[sometext%]')

This performs a local search so it first downloads all the Subject headers and then it matches them against the regular expression. But, it does not match anything.
What would be the correct way to match the [sometext] string in my subjects?
UPDATE
I gave up on trying to find how to make an exact search on an IMAP server. I tried using other clients than Imapfilter and even telnet directly into the IMAP server to verify the results of a SEARCH command, and they all behaved in the same way, returning wrong results. So the sloppy search issue is on the IMAP server side.
So what I ended up doing is a two pass operation. First I send the SEARCH, then I filter the search results on the client side to eliminate the wrong ones. Not ideal but I have no more time to waste on this.
I'll let the question open in case someone finds a solution.

%[sometext%] is a correct Lua patten to match [sometext] text. How can we repro the issue?

It doesn't work, unfortunately. I just installed imapfilter on an Ubuntu Server and it should work. We use Zimbra as our mail server.

IMAP text search is inclusive, not exact. The specification says (I'm paraphrasing here, not being exact) that the server should include this and and that in the result, without saying that it should exclude anything. This gives servers scope to include borderline cases, or to simplify their code by disregarding non-letters, or, or, or.
The above implies that can assume that what you want will be in the server's result, but if you need an exact search, you have to check again on the client. The server will give you all the matches you want and maybe a few spurious extras.
(A common example of this is that if you search for "answers", the server may include a message that mentions "answer", because its search engine works on word stems rather than exactly.)

I do not agree with your interpretation of the IMAP SEARCH function. See the RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4 6.4.4.  SEARCH Command

Or RFC 9051 section 6.4.4.

FYI, digressing… someone once asked Mark Crispin about this. Mark answered that he intended to allow flexible matching in RFCs 2060/3501, I've forgotten which RFC was current at the time. If he'd wanted seach text "foo bar" to disallow matching foo\nbar, his personal writing style would have been to definie "contains" strictly in 2060/3501 6.4.4. But he left the verb undefined.

In all search keys that use strings, and unless otherwise specified, a message matches the key if the string is a substring of the associated text. The matching SHOULD be case insensitive for characters within the ASCII range.

Mark Crispin, the author of those words, was the kind of person who distinguished between "…if the string…" and "…if and only if the string…" Read the quotation exactly, think about what it would mean if it said "… if and only if the string…". Mark left out "and only if" by choice. That distinction is too subtle for most people, which is the reason that the most recent wording uses several sentences and the "swim" example.

BTW, the second sentence quoted is also a great example of Mark's extremely concise writing style. The sentence doesn't imply that non-ASCII should be treated case sensitively. It is quiet on the subject, because Mark didn't want to formulate a rule. So: the first sentence says 'if(search key is substring) then match else unspecified' and the second says 'if(search key character is ascii) then case-insensitive else unspecified'.

I fail to see the difference between an "if" and an "if and only if". A condition is either true or it is not.

What's happening is that the clear rule if the string is a substring is not respected by IMAP servers, or at least by Zimbra, our mail server. [foo] is not a substring of foo bar. foo, however, is. But the IMAP server treats [foo] like a substring of foo bar which is plain wrong according to the RFC.

Anyways I ended up doing like you said, filtering the search results on the client side.

"x is true if and only if y" means that x is true if y, and only in that case. "x is true if y" means that x is true if y, but not necessarily only in that case. People are generally sloppy about the distinction. Compiler authors and a few others take this kind of thing very seriously, though.

Yes okay, understood. So a message matches the key if the string is a substring of the associated text must be understood as there are possibly other cases where a message matches the key, and those cases are not documented. It means that the RFC is incomplete.

Right. There are quite a few cases like this around the edges of the RFCs, where Mark (and later Alexey) tried to specify enough to be useful for clients, while leaving enough flexibility to make it easy for server authors.
